# How to reset CountDownTimer on activity resume?

Tags: java, android

I don't use constant value for my countdown timer, cause it's different time for every next level.So I use timeCount variable set at 150000 for the first level:

```
    long timeCount = 150000;

public String formatTime(long millis) {  
                    String output = "00:00";  
                    long seconds = millis / 1000;  
                    long minutes = seconds / 60;  

                    seconds = seconds % 60;  
                    minutes = minutes % 60;  

                    String sec = String.valueOf(seconds);  
                    String min = String.valueOf(minutes);  

                    if (seconds < 10)  
                        sec = "0" + seconds;  
                    if (minutes < 10)  
                        min= "0" + minutes;  

                    output = min + " : " + sec;  
                    return output;
                }
```

And my timer:

```
public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
         public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
             super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
         }

         public void onFinish() {


         }
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             vreme.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         }
         }
    // New timer for 40 minutes, starts after initialization
   MyCount brojacVremena = new MyCount(timeCount, 1000) 
   {
       // Updates the text on your "scoreboard" every second
       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
       {
           vreme.setText("" + formatTime(millisUntilFinished));
       }

       public void onFinish() 
       {
        finish();
       }
   };
```

So, when the game ends, i present a popup window and the next level is up after OK is pressed. I call the popup and set new values, for time and some other stuff:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Kviz.this, Popup_nivoi.class);
            if(level==2){
                numberOfQuestions = 13;
                timeCount = 160000;
                greska = 7;
                level++;
}
brojacVremena.cancel();
            startActivityForResult(i, MY_REQUEST2);
```

But my countdowntimer always starts from the old time, 150000ms. How to reset it, cause me changing the timeCount value does not do the job. I don't know why. That variable is changed, I know that for sure, but countdown timer does not use it.

Comment: Maybe in the method `onResume`of your `Activity`?

Comment: You read more about Activity Lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: Did you even read my question? I know what is onResume method, I just not understand what should I do in it that can solve my problem. You can answer me that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not reset time in already created `CountDownTimer` it is immutable object and your `timeCount` varibale is used only once when creating this object. So what you need to do is just create another timer with new time.

**UPD:** Here is some code

```
public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
     public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
         super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         finish();
     }

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         vreme.setText("" + formatTime(millisUntilFinished));
     }
}
MyCount brojacVremena = new MyCount(timeCount, 1000);
```

Then when you need new timer you have to just write

`brojacVremena = new MyCount(timeCount, 1000);`

with new `timeCount` variable.

Comment: I have 20 levels. So I need 20 timers??

Comment: Yes, that's right, but you don't have to keep all of them in memory. Once you need new timer you can replace old timer with it.

Comment: Can you help me out me the code? I can use my main timer code for all timers?

Comment: Thanks a lot. You mentioned "you don't have to keep all of them in memory". How to do that?

Comment: That means you have just one field for Timer and every time you assign new instance to it means that old instance would be garbage collected. So if you did as I described then everything is ok and you are not keeping them all in memory.

Comment: OK. But it does not work well when I just use brojacVremena = new MyCount(timeCount, 1000);. I counts down but not in 00:00 format, but in 249,248...I have to use the rest of the code to make it in 00:00 format.

Comment: Actually it does not work at all. I have to use the whole snippet below MyCount brojacVremena = new MyCount(timeCount, 1000);. A lot of code, but the only way it works.